# Is it possible to cheat thumb drive Serial Number?

Tags: usb-drive, piracy-protection

I want to distribute my software on flash (thumb) drives. The software protection will check that the product runs from a flash drive with predefined Serial Number thus protecting me from the software unauthorized duplication.

My question is if it possible to somehow create another flash drive with the same Serial Number? E.g. if a flash drive exist which allows for SN modification? Or are some other ways exist to cheat such protection?

Comment: Even without any knowledge of the subject, I'm quite sure the answers are: Yes, it is possible modify the S/N, and, yes, there are plenty of ways to crack any kind of protection.

Comment: RoToRa, not sure your answer helps. Of course, I can go to a factory and ask them to make duplicate, but the cost of that will be too much. I am asking of regular ways to do this.

Comment: Well, it wasn't an answer just a comment ;-) And I wasn't talking of "going to a factory". I'm quite sure there are software only solutions (see Michael's answer). What kind of answers are you looking for? Common sense and basic computer knowledge says there is absolutely no way to prevent the copying of software - with or without USB sticks.

Comment: RoToRa, I understand. I mean - "cheap way". If it is required to go to a factory or spend say it one man-month of efforts, this is OK - both ways are more expensive than software costs.
My guess was that maybe there are some kind of programmable usb stick with easy-to-change SN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you actually read the hardware SN rather than the partition ID. The USB spec does not require a hardware SN, [but there usually is one](http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Retrieving_Non-Volatile_USB_Serial_Number_Using_C_Sharp.cfm).

> E.g. if a flash drive exist which allows for SN modification?

It's certainly possible to build such a device.

> Or are some other ways exist to cheat
>   such protection?

The USB driver could be modified to spoof the serial, or (probably easier) the checking code could be removed from the program. Such software modifications are a much bigger threat than hypothetical "SN faking hardware", because unlike hardware they can be distributed over the internet instantly and for free.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will use Xenocode or CodeVeil (now known as DeployLX) which help with the software modification. So I feel more or less secure about the code modification and only afraid of SN cheat.